# Social media and my own login/register in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, authentication

I'm started developing apps for iOS 4 months ago, and I'm getting the hang of it. Now I want the take it to the next level with login and register options in my new app. But I don't really know the right approach for this.

- When using the social media api's (Facebook/Twitter) and the user uses this to register and login. Do I need to save this register in my own sql database? So I can hook data to the user like, how many clicks did the user do on stuff? Or how is this handled?
- Can this be the database where I can store my own register/login options for users that don't have social media or does not want to use it for my app.
- All requests from and to my server, are they fully secured when using https? Or how do I need to secure this so user can not sniff the network for the information (hackers and stuff, you'll never know lol)

I did some research but I can not find stuff about this, probably because I'm dutch, and do not really know how to formulate my questions in google about this stuff. If anyone can pass me some tutorials and information about this topic, this would be really helpful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not really asking one question, you're asking 20 questions. Each one needs to be asked separately, and most of them probably have already been answered here. I suggest you write down a list of all the things you're not sure about, research each one individually, and record the results for yourself. Then you can proceed with the project. :-) I'm voting to close this as too broad.

Answer (score 2):

1) Facebook lets you get user's email, username, photos etc. But they won't give you the user's password. So what I suggest is you should make the user sign up with face book's username and email, but make user set up a password as well then save all that in your own sql database.

2) Save Facebook login users and normal login users in the same table. Media login or not your sql database should have at least email, username, password from every user.

3) Are you using PHP to connect to you sql database? If so, to prevent hackers you should use PDO or MySQLi. Read this question to understand more about how to prevent MySQL injection: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Hope this helps :)